# How do I write to strings.xml with data from a database in Android?

Tags: android, database, string

I am trying to make my Android application more dynamic. All the strings are in the strings.xml file and retrieved with R.string. 
Now I would like to fill strings.xml with data from a database. I know how to fetch data and use it, but I don't understand how I can write to the strings.xml. 
I read that SharedPreferences is one way of retrieving key-value pairs of data, but not sure if that is the best way to go.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Resources are precompiled. In strings.xml are stored constant values. 
Dynamic solution should be based on database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to strings.xml. In is included in your apk file during build time and is not modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Strings.xml is processed at compile-time, you can't modify it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make two folders of string and from database according to users preference stored in database you should load the strings from that folder.

```
public static String getResourceString(String name, Context context)
 {
    int nameResourceID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (nameResourceID == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No resource string found with name " + name);
    } else {
        return context.getString(nameResourceID);
    }
}
```

Comment: _hope this helps_ can't judge the content - but would be more helpful if it were easily readable (or in other words: please edit and format the code :-)